# App State: Static variables or Setters and Getters in JAVA

Tags: java, android

Well i want to know one of the state of my application across my classes.Is it good to use a Static boolean variable or to use a Singleton class which has Getters and Setters methods.
Brief on the advantage and disadvantage on the approach.

Comment: i prefer ... its better to have singleton class ..

Comment: A syncronized singleton class

Comment: In a Singleton you can take more control over how getter/setter occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make it static in order to change the state from other classes you have make it public. Also having getters and setters for static variables makes no sense as they are class variables. Also making variables public is not a good programming practice. So a better option would be have a singleton class and have the getter and setter methods of the state variable. Also if you are in a multi threaded environment make the variable volatile for proper synchronization.

Comment: Cheers for your ans! commenting on " Also having getters and setters for static variables makes no sense as they are class variables." my Getters and Setters methods will have private non static variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many good reasons to consider using accessors rather than directly exposing fields of a class - beyond just the argument of encapsulation and making future changes easier.

Here are the some of the reasons I am aware of:

- Encapsulation of behavior associated with getting or setting the
  property - this allows additional functionality (like validation) to
  be added more easily later.
- Hiding the internal representation of the property while exposing a
  property using an alternative representation.
- Insulating your public interface from change - allowing the public
  interface to remain constant while the implementation changes without
  effecting existing consumers.
- Controlling the lifetime and memory management (disposal) semantics
  of the property - particularly important in non-managed memory
  environments (like C++ or Objective-C).
- Providing a debugging interception point for when a property changes
  at runtime - debugging when and where a property changed to a
  particular value can be quite difficult without this in some
  languages.
- Improved interoperability with libraries that are designed to operate
  against property getter/setters - Mocking, Serialization, and WPF
  come to mind.
- Allowing inheritors to change the semantics of how the property
  behaves and is exposed by overriding the getter/setter methods.
- Allowing the getter/setter to be passed around as lambda expressions
  rather than values.
- Getters and setters can allow different access levels - for example
  the get may be public, but the set could be protected.

Answer (score 0):

The Singleton pattern has several advantages over static classes.

1. A singleton can extend classes and implement interfaces, while a static class cannot (it can extend classes, but it does not inherit their instance members).
2. A singleton can be initialized lazily or asynchronously while a static class is generally initialized when it is first loaded, leading to potential class loader issues.
3. The most important advantage, though, is that singletons can be handled polymorphically without forcing their users to assume that there is only one instance.

[This](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/03/difference-between-singleton-pattern-vs-static-class-java.html) may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference b/w Singleton and a bunch of static methods is that singletons can implement interfaces so you can pass around the singleton as if it were "just another" implementation.

Also you can clone the object of Singleton but, we can not clone the static class object.